# box-sizing + border + absolute child

Tags: html, css

I recently discovered this problem.

[Check for demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/)

As for me, the outline behaves wrong, doesn’t it? Shouldn’t the box model of the `.outside` element include its borders, so that the `absolute` positioned child element outlines those borders aswell?

Is this a known problem? Is this really correct behavior? If so, could someone explain to me why it is?

[What I expected to have as result](https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/2/)

Please do not comment on how to solve the problem. But please explain why the problem occurs.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards 
phlips

Comment: you didn't set `border` but `outline`... that is the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/1/ - now with border - same problem

Comment: wait.. what are you asking actually? you want border from inside div to be where?

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/2/ - and check the result. Shouldn’t this be the result?

Answer (score 4):

Just `box-sizing: border-box` is not enough, you need to inherit width and height from parent:

```
.inside {
  position: absolute;
  outline: #00f solid 2px;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Check here https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/3/

Comment: Okay thank you. But why didn’t `top / left / right / bottom: 0` work here?

Comment: Because you didn't set width/height.. there was no width/height inherited so child can't know what is new size of parent that is set with new box-sizing.

Answer (score 3):

In this case when using position: absolute ..

> .. the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the ancestor.

See [CSS Specifications - 10.1 Definition of "containing block"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

For whatever reason..

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because `position: absolute` which will position an element relative to a container. By default, the container is the browser window, but if a parent element either has `position: relative` or `position: absolute` set on it, then it will act as the parent for **positioning coordinates for its children**.

With parent, you have 2 attributes:

```
border-right: 50px #f5f solid;
border-bottom: 50px #f5f solid;
```

If you remove it, outline will be full size, because you set 4 attributes: `top, right, bottom, left` is 0. (change it to see the change).

Comment: Okay yes. But shouldn’t the borders be inside my parent container due to `box-sizing: border-box`? And therefore the child element cover the parent’s borders?

Comment: I guess you get me wrong. With this code (https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/) I expected this result (https://jsfiddle.net/2mytb43a/2).